# XHR request finished, but variable not catched properly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "shop/system/library/cart.php?csp=" + $('#input-custom-price').val(),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log($('#input-custom-price').val());
            }
        });
    });
});
```

in case , when i send this variable, to my own php i can read the variable with GET:

```
$csp = $_GET['csp'];
```

This is working perfectly.
But when i try to send to cart.php (which is an opencart file), i always get an error:
"Notice: Undefined index: csp in ... on line 314" 
So i edited my code:

```
$csp = (isset($_GET['csp']) ? $_GET['csp'] : 10);
```

Now there isn't error message, but the php always calculate with 10. Any idea?

Comment: How does the request look in the console? Chrome's dev tools can really shine a light on things like that

Comment: XHR finished loading: GET "http://************.***/shop/system/library/cart.php?csp=100".

Comment: Are there any redirects or Apache rewrite rules involved? They might kill off the GET vars. You might want to try using POST instead of GET with the AJAX request.

Comment: Nothing in particular, however works, when i send this request to another php.

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Try the POST instead to just try to eliminate the possibility. Also try a `var_dump($_SERVER); die();` to make sure the URL is being picked up properly.

Comment: Added line to ajax: type: 'post', and and in cart.php POST instead of GET, console says: XHR finished loading: POST "http://**********.***/shop/system/library/cart.php?csp=100". but the result is same, calculated, with 10.

Comment: You need to move your `?csp=100` into the `data` attribute: `$.ajax({..., data: {csp: $('#input-custom-price').val()}}`.

Comment: Same result.  There is another script, that using the same JS event. Can this cause the problem?

Comment: What does it look like? And what does the console say about the POST request?

Comment: XHR finished loading: POST "http://**********.***/shop/system/library/cart.php". 100

Comment: And the another script:
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
 $.ajax({
  url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
  type: 'post',
  data: $('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select, #product textarea'),
  dataType: 'json',

Comment: So what does the `var_dump($_SERVER); die();` look like on the PHP side?